# Align cell content in excel using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlwings

I am struggling to set the alignment for data in excel using python

My python function loads data from excel into a pandas dataframe, calculates some new columns, then adds these columns to the original sheet. This all works well, but I now want to tidy up the result.

I can set italics / bold etc using

```
sheet['E1:J24'].font.bold = True
sheet['E1:J24'].font.italic = True
```

But I cannot set the alignment properly. I have tried the following, and several other suggestions I found online, but none of them seems to work.

```
sheet['E1:J24'].alignment = Alignment(horizontal="center")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Update to question,

With further on-line searching I came upon this line of code which successfully adjusts the alignment.

```
sheet.range(f'$E1:J24').api.HorizontalAlignment = -4152
```

I think the problem is that I connected to the worksheet using xlwings and then tried to use openpyxl to format it. Jupyter didn't give an error because I had imported 'Alignment' from openpyxl

Note, for alignments use setting as follows

```
center = -4108
right = -4152
Left = -4131
```

Not sure where the numbers come from

Answer (score 0):

Use 'VerticalAlignment' and/or 'HorizontalAlignment'.
Import VAlign, HAlign from the Xlwings constants to use the name or just use the Excel code. I have copied these into the comments for your information.

```
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings.constants import VAlign, HAlign

### Xlwings constants
"""
VAlign Class
xlVAlignBottom = -4107
xlVAlignCenter = -4108
xlVAlignDistributed = -4117
xlVAlignJustify = -4130
xlVAlignTop = -4160 

HAlign Class
xlHAlignCenter = -4108
xlHAlignCenterAcrossSelection = 7
xlHAlignDistributed = -4117
xlHAlignFill = 5
xlHAlignGeneral = 1
xlHAlignJustify = -4130
xlHAlignLeft = -4131
xlHAlignRight = -4152
"""


path = "foo.xlsx"

with xw.App() as app:
    wb = xw.Book(path)
    ws = wb.sheets[0]

    # Align text vertically 
    ws.range(1, 1).api.VerticalAlignment = -4160
    ws.range(1, 2).api.VerticalAlignment = VAlign.xlVAlignCenter
    ws.range(1, 3).api.VerticalAlignment = VAlign.xlVAlignBottom
    # Align text horizontally
    ws.range(2, 1).api.HorizontalAlignment = HAlign.xlHAlignLeft
    ws.range(2, 2).api.HorizontalAlignment = HAlign.xlHAlignCenter
    ws.range(2, 3).api.HorizontalAlignment = -4152

    wb.save(path)
    wb.close()
```

Comment: Very nice, I have added your answer to my reference material